# Force a validation group to fail if a condition isn't met

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a group of text boxes that have required field validation hooked up to them. Obviously they all share the same validation group name. I have a check box for terms of service that needs to be checked before clicking on the submit button actually does anything.

Is there some C# code that will say if this box isn't checked, fail the validation group?

Or is there a better way?

edit:
I added a custom validator and used this in my code behind. Does not work.

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;
    if (cbxTerms.Checked)
        args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Why not give the CheckBox a CustomValidator and add it to the same Validation Group?

Comment: Have you tried using Custom validator?

Comment: please see my edit above, I saw this solution on you tube but it doesn't work for me. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please don't put things like "C#" in the title - please just use tags for that.

Comment: John, thanks for answering my question, you're very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I made a textbox, assigned a req field validator to it. Put the textbox 99999px off the screen. In my c# i said if the check box is checked, the textbox.text = ""; in the checkbox check changed event I said if the check box is checked then the textbox.text = "1";. Much easier than any other solution I could find

Edit: Better to use a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would just use JavaScript. When the page loads, attach a client side event handler to the buttons submit. Inside the handler check to see if the checkbox is checked, if so then return true otherwise return false which should cancel the submit. If JavaScript is turned off then thats OK too because you should have some server side validation happening because people can sumbit forms in other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you did above but with a return if not checked like that

```
if (!cbxTerms.Checked) 
{requiredlabel.text="*";
return;}
```

You can set a label manually to tell the user that ths field is needed

Comment: The problem I'm having though is that even with the code I provided, the validation group that the button uses is not failing when the box isn't checked.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Mitchell had an article on this.
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121907-1.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20210304131838/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092006-1.aspx

I think it's a slightly different approach, but I used it a while ago to handle a similar situation and it seemed to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

you can even prevent postback if checkbox is not checked

```
Button1.Attributes["onclick"] =
        "if (!$get('" + CheckBox1.ClientID + "').checked){alert('Agree with us,plz!');return false;}";
```

why doing all the validation stuff if it can be prevented :)

or if you thurst for forcing group to invalid tou can do it win your own validation on client side:

```
function myStartUpValidation(group){
    var result=true;
    //Page_ClientValidate(group); to validate group
    for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { 
        if(Page_Validators[i].validationGroup==group){
        try{
            ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]); //this forces validation in all groups
            if(Page_Validators[i].isvalid==false){result=false;}
            }catch(err){}
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

or an extra validator...